# How to store logged In user_id in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am totally new in vew js and I am trying to store data in db and I am storing successfully when I entered the values manually but I want to store the `user_id` of logged in user.

Here is my vue

```
<form @submit.prevent>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="event_name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="event_name" class="form-control" v-model="newEvent.event_name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="user_id">Use Id</label>
    <input type="text" id="user_id" class="form-control" v-model="newEvent.user_id">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 mb-4" v-if="addingMode">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @click="addNewEvent">Save Event</button>
  </div>
</form>

export default {
  components: {
    Fullcalendar
  },
  data() {
    return {
      calendarPlugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
      events: "",
      newEvent: {
        event_name: "",
        user_id: ""
      },
      addingMode: true,
      indexToUpdate: ""
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getEvents();
  },
  methods: {
    addNewEvent() {
      axios
        .post("/fullcalendar/api/calendar", {
          ...this.newEvent
        })
        .then(data => {
          this.getEvents(); // update our list of events
          this.resetForm(); // clear newEvent properties (e.g. title and user_id)
        })
        .catch(err =>
          console.log("Unable to add new event!", err.response.data)
        );
    },
```

Here, when I enter values in Name and User Id manually then it stores in db but in user id I want to get the logged in user_id.

I have tried something like this but it didn't work,

```
<input type="text" id="user_id" class="form-control" v-model="newEvent.{{ Auth::user()->id; }}">
```

Please help me out, Thanks in advance.

EventResource.php

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->event_name,
            'user' => $this->user_id,
        ];
    }
```

Comment: store where? in you database?

Comment: yes, in database

Comment: please post the controller code you're using to save data. you can simply pass `Auth::user()->id` over there

Comment: I have created a EventResource and adding through it, I have updated above

Comment: what's stopping you from doing this: `'user' => auth()->user()->id,`

Comment: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default

Comment: try this maybe: `'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,`

Comment: Same error is showing

Comment: Is it possible to show anyhow the user_id here

Answer (score 0):

you can send data with your axios request like this:

```
  axios.post('/url', {
       user_id: {{ Auth::user()->id }}
     }, {
       headers: headers
     })
```

and in your controller you can access it with:`$request->user_id;`